# How do you block the latest popups (not sure if they're FLASH based, etc.)

Tags: firefox, popups

I'm using FF 3.5 and have popup blocker enabled. But I'm still getting popups. I'm guessing their flash based. The real annoyance is that they cover the text of the website and (in some cases like the one below) don't have a "close" button.

An example of a popup that appears and annoying covers the text.

http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-xp/absolute-uninstaller-uninstall-your-unwanted-applications-easily-in-vista2003xp2000/

Comment: not sure what you're talking about; i don't see it on the sample link.  i think what you describe is a kind of javascript "pop-up" a bit like the notification bar that appears at the top of this website.  can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I've seen the type of "popup" he's referring to.  They're not a new window, per se.  I think they're Javascript based.  Microsoft pages sometimes use them, for example.  I use FF3.5.6, and AdBlock Plus, and I still get "some"?  Some may be blocked, but ABP doesn't have the necessary strings to block them all.  Still, I think ABP doesn't a pretty good job, regardless.

Comment: Please provide a working link or screenshot and/or let us know if the link @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 provided solved your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [AdBlockPlus](http://adblockplus.org/)!

If indeed the ads are Flash-based, you could also try [FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433).

Comment: +1 for both ABP and Flashblock. I use both and they work well together. Also Flashblock means sites like myspace don't immediately start playing music (which gets really annoying).